# how vim map two command

Tags: vim

I am wondering how to use one hotkey mapping two command in vim.
for exmpale, I already have those two mapping

```
map <silent> <F7> zM
map <silent> <F8> zR
```

But, I just want to use F8 to toggle between zM and zR.
Hoping anyone can give me solution.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Won't zA do what you wanted...?

If it won't then we need to go deeper. http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1494 tells you what to do, here's the relevant script:

```
map <buffer> F8 :call ToggleFold()<CR> 
let b:folded = 1 
function! ToggleFold() 
  if( b:folded == 0 ) 
      exec "normal! zM" 
      let b:folded = 1 
  else 
      exec "normal! zR" 
      let b:folded = 0 
  endif 
endfunction
```

Comment: actually, zA already mapped to <space>, but it only toggle one fold. I mean I want to toggle all folds. (zA does not do that)

Comment: Edited my reply to accomodate your wish.